# How do I install Jetty WTP Server Adapter for Eclipse 3.5?

Tags: jetty, eclipse-wtp, eclipse-3.5

Currently I am attempting to install the Jetty WTP Server Adapter for Eclipse 3.5 and get the following errors:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.mortbay.jetty.serveradaptor,1.0.4
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.mortbay.jetty.serveradaptor,1.0.4
```

To install, I attempt to add a new server runtime, click 'Install Additional Server Adapters' and follow the wizard I get when I click on the Generic Jetty Server Adapter that eventually loads. I've had this error in all the RCs up to this point, but currently the active RC is RC4.

Answer (score 15):

I also found the 'Download additional server adapters" route to adding the Jetty (and Glassfish) server adapters failed, with the same dependency issues as the Original Poster.

Downloading the .jar and copying it into the 'plugins' dir of my Eclipse install idd not work.  The Jetty server adapter was still not a recognised installed plugin.

I had to go to "Help->Install New Software->Add..." and enter the http://www.webtide.com/eclipse site manually.  Then I could see the Jetty adapter, and install it successfully.  It seems to have installed into the eclipse/plugins/ rather than copied a .jar file into eclipse/plugins.

This may be what the poster on 2 Jul was trying to say, but it wasn't very clear.

I don't know why, but the "download additional server adapters" dialog hasn't worked for me once with Eclipse 3.5, the install always fails with dependency issues.

I also found I had to manually install all the WST Adapter items to get around failed dependencies, for example:

"Web, XML and Java EE Development->JST Server Adapters", "WST Server Adapters"

and also the "Database Development" items.  I'm not sure which were required.. when I'd installed everything that looked likely, all my dependency issues were resolved when installing the Glassfish and Jetty server adapters from their update sites.

Comment: The correct "work with" URL is now: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-wtp. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty_WTP_Plugin/Jetty_WTP_Install for installation instructions.

Answer (score 8):

There's a new (official!) Jetty WTP Plugin to support Jetty 7.x and 8.x: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty_WTP_Plugin

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be resolved installing the JST Server UI before the Jetty Server Adapter. It is a current bug (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321663). 
That way you can install it either as a plugin or in the servers view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need org.mortbay.jetty.serveradaptor.1.0.4.jar to install jetty adapter, download from http://www.webtide.com/eclipse , put it in plugins of eclipse.

Hope the answer could help you.